# Reference FilterScheme's Name in Spotfire

Tags: python, filter, ironpython, spotfire

I'd like to know how to reference a single filter within a scheme by name so I can clear it. But all the demonstrations I've found use ActiveFilteringSelectionReference so I'm having trouble figuring out how to write this script to target filters that are not the active filter on the page.

Specifically I need to reset the filter on the column "Team" of the Table "Timesheets" for the filtering scheme "TeamFilter". Here is my start. Line five is an error because FilteringSchemes does not want to take a string, but I don't know how to give it the name of the filter I want to reference.

```
import Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters as filters
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters import *

myScheme = Document.FilteringSchemes["TeamFilter"]
myTable = Document.Data.Tables["Timesheets"]

filt=Document.FilteringSchemes[myScheme][myTable][myTable.Columns["Team"]]

filt.Reset()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
#Reset filters across all filter schemes
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters import *

#Get the active page and filterPanel
page = Application.Document.ActivePageReference
filterPanel = page.FilterPanel
#Find Filter Scheme
for scheme in Document.FilteringSchemes:  
  if scheme.FilteringSelectionReference.Name == 'Test':
    filterPanel.FilteringSchemeReference = scheme
    print(scheme.FilteringSelectionReference.Name)

#Reset Filter for Specific
filterPanel.InteractiveSearchPattern = "Country" 
for filter in filterPanel.FiltersMatchingSearchPattern:
    if filter.FilterReference.Name == "Country":
        lbFilter = filter.FilterReference.As[ListBoxFilter]() 
    lbFilter.Reset()
```

https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-get-or-set-specific-filter-using-ironpython-script-tibco-spotfire
https://community.tibco.com/questions/how-reset-filtering-scheme-script
https://community.tibco.com/questions/how-can-i-use-iironpython-script-set-filtering-scheme-multiple-tabs

Comment: I understand that the below code works because its iterating thru the list of filtering schemes until the name of one matches. But how can we just say print Document.FilteringSchemes['test']? I'm trying to get around using interactive search pattern and setting the active page filter. Why should the code have to pretend to use the interface as a human would?

for scheme in Document.FilteringSchemes:  
  if scheme.FilteringSelectionReference.Name == 'test':
    print(scheme.FilteringSelectionReference.Name)

Comment: Not quite sure , Can't find a single example of it not being done in this method. I don't believe you can reference a scheme with a string so the loop is necessary to set the variable. Besides the look of the code it would still function the same. The posted code does work to reset your filter and is not using  ActiveFilteringSelectionReference. Up voting or approving an answer is always appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You can reference a `FilteringScheme` or `FilterSelection` directly with this code:

```
Document.FilteringSchemes[Document.Data.Filterings["YourFilteringScheme"]]
```